# Relay built in to cable with arduino interface

Tags: power, relay

To be able to switch 220 volt stuff on and off using arduino, I need a relay (I assume). Is there really no nice extention cable with built in relay so you dont need to cut and connect high voltage.

I imagine a Power strip With a simple input port that can be controlled from the andruino, just like a relay board. When I Google this I get a lot of USB controlled and remote controlled, but none that works with an andruino project.

Answer (score 1):

[PowerSwitch Tail](http://www.powerswitchtail.com/Pages/default.aspx) is what you are looking for.